# How to call K2 currently viewed item's title / creation date on my template index.php?

Tags: templates, k2

As mentioned in the title, I'd like to know how to call the K2 current item's title & creation date in my template's *index.php*.

What I'm trying to achieve is to display (if the user is on a K2 item's page ) the title and creation date of a K2 item somewhere else ( in the *index.php* of my template for example).

The thing is that I'd like to completely move the title/created date from K2 items to a module position on my template.

I've done a lot of researches but couldn't find anything but this, that works well, but only for Joomla article's titles, not K2's:

```
$option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
$view = JRequest::getCmd('view');
if ($option=="com_content" && $view=="article") {
    $ids = explode(':',JRequest::getString('id'));
    $article_id = $ids[0];
    $article =& JTable::getInstance("content");
    $article->load($article_id);
    echo $article->get("title");
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can do something similar like:

```
$app    = JFactory::getApplication();
$jinput = $app->input; 
$option = $jinput->getCmd('option');
$view   = $jinput->getCmd('view');

if ($option=="com_k2" && $view=="item") 
{

    $item_id = $jinput->getInt('id');

    JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_k2/tables');
    $item = JTable::getInstance('K2Item', 'Table', array());
    $item->load($item_id);

    echo $item->title;

}
```